# How to describe factors leading to a negative event?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, verbs, science

Being a non-native English speaker, I am looking for an appropriate verb/phrase to **describe the negative event** as consequence of two health factors.

My best shot is "precipitate"; however, I am concerned whether this is correct.

> Extent of surgical resection and the proliferative index of remaining 
>       tumor cells must be considered key precipitating factors of recurrence.

(That is recurrence of the tumor).

Thank you in advance. 
Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common phrase is "risk factors".  This conveys the idea that no one factor completely determines the negative event, but they all change the odds.

Comment: This answer needs at least one reference.